# Derived class copy-constructor not entered in favor of copy-constructor taking parent class reference instead

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, conditional-operator, dynamic-cast

Consider a hierarchy

```
base_dir -> base_dir_ext -> server
                       \--> location
```

with the following reduced code containing a method that, through inheritance, sometimes accepts a `server`, sometimes a `location`, and needs to instantiate a `location` from it. Using the following `main()`, everything works fine and the `location` copy-constructor is entered.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class base_dir
{
    // shared inherited member
    public:
        base_dir() { };
        virtual ~base_dir() { };
};

class base_dir_ext : public base_dir
{
    // even more shared inherited members
    public:
        base_dir_ext() { };
        virtual ~base_dir_ext() { };
        base_dir_ext(const base_dir_ext &other);
        base_dir_ext(const base_dir &other);
};

class server : public base_dir_ext
{
    public:
        server() { };
        ~server() { };
        server(const server &other);
        // server(const base_dir &other);
        server &operator=(const server &other);
};

class location : public base_dir_ext
{
    public:
        location() { };
        ~location() { };
        location(const location&) : base_dir_ext()
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR LOCATION ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }

        location(const base_dir&)
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR BASE_DIR ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }

        location(const server&) : base_dir_ext()
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR SERVER ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }
};

base_dir *process_location(base_dir *parent)
{
    std::cout << "typeid: " << typeid(*(dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) ? dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) : parent)).name() << std::endl;
    location loc((dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) ? dynamic_cast<location&>(*parent) : dynamic_cast<server&>(*parent)));
    // process location and add it to `parent`
    return (parent);
}

int main()
{
    location loc;

    base_dir *parent = &loc;

    process_location(parent);
}
```

Output:

```
typeid: 8location
COPY-CTOR FOR LOCATION ENTERED
```

However, as you may have noticed, I had to comment out `server::server(const base_dir &other)`, i.e. `server`'s constructor that takes `base_dir`. When I uncomment it,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class base_dir
{
    // shared inherited member
    public:
        base_dir() { };
        virtual ~base_dir() { };
};

class base_dir_ext : public base_dir
{
    // even more shared inherited members
    public:
        base_dir_ext() { };
        virtual ~base_dir_ext() { };
        base_dir_ext(const base_dir_ext &other);
        base_dir_ext(const base_dir &other);
};

class server : public base_dir_ext
{
    public:
        server() { };
        ~server() { };
        server(const server &other);
        server(const base_dir &other);
        server &operator=(const server &other);
};

class location : public base_dir_ext
{
    public:
        location() { };
        ~location() { };
        location(const location&) : base_dir_ext()
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR LOCATION ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }

        location(const base_dir&)
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR BASE_DIR ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }

        location(const server&) : base_dir_ext()
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR SERVER ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }
};

base_dir *process_location(base_dir *parent)
{
    std::cout << "typeid: " << typeid(*(dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) ? dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) : parent)).name() << std::endl;
    location loc((dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) ? dynamic_cast<location&>(*parent) : dynamic_cast<server&>(*parent)));
    // process location and add it to `parent`
    return (parent);
}

int main()
{
    location loc;

    base_dir *parent = &loc;

    process_location(parent);
}
```

a compiler error is generated:

```
$ c++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'base_dir* process_location(base_dir*)':
main.cpp:54:48: error: operands to ?: have different types 'location' and 'server'  location loc((dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) ? dynamic_cast<location&>(*parent) : dynamic_cast<server&>(*parent)));
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:54:48: note:   and each type can be converted to the other
```

My question is: why does this happen? Why all of a sudden `server` and `location` appear to be different classes? Don't they count as equivalent as they have the same parent and grandparent?

To get rid of this error, I tried removing dynamic cast of `parent` to `server&` type in `process_location()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class base_dir
{
    // shared inherited member
    public:
        base_dir() { };
        virtual ~base_dir() { };
};

class base_dir_ext : public base_dir
{
    // even more shared inherited members
    public:
        base_dir_ext() { };
        virtual ~base_dir_ext() { };
        base_dir_ext(const base_dir_ext &other);
        base_dir_ext(const base_dir &other);
};

class server : public base_dir_ext
{
    public:
        server() { };
        ~server() { };
        server(const server &other);
        server(const base_dir &other);
        server &operator=(const server &other);
};

class location : public base_dir_ext
{
    public:
        location() { };
        ~location() { };
        location(const location&) : base_dir_ext()
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR LOCATION ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }

        location(const base_dir&)
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR BASE_DIR ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }

        location(const server&) : base_dir_ext()
        {
            std::cout << "COPY-CTOR FOR SERVER ENTERED" << std::endl;
        }
};

base_dir *process_location(base_dir *parent)
{
    std::cout << "typeid: " << typeid(*(dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) ? dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) : parent)).name() << std::endl;
    location loc((dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) ? dynamic_cast<location&>(*parent) : *parent));
    // process location and add it to `parent`
    return (parent);
}

int main()
{
    location loc;

    base_dir *parent = &loc;

    process_location(parent);
}
```

But then, while `typeid()` clearly outputs location type, location's `const base_dir&` constructor is invoked instead of its own copy-constructor. Why?
The output:

```
typeid: 8location
COPY-CTOR FOR BASE_DIR ENTERED
```

Why does the only presence of `server(const base_dir &other);` ruin the ternary? I do not wish to remove this method since I want my classes to be versatile. Is there anything I miss about inheritance that doesn't let my code add up? I'd prefer to preserve the first version of code with the server constructor method uncommented: is that possible?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. When the question is about a compiler error please post the code that has the error rather than code that is fine but requires to be modified to reproduce the issue

Comment: btw the part you left out is crucial `// process location and add it to parent`, because without that its not obvious whether the ternary is actually needed or not

Comment: ot: `server serv(void);` in main declares a function (it just doesnt matter because you are using `serv`)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry, I'll stitch the code together for you. I did not want to include that part to make it more minimal

Comment: oh well ok I was wrong about the `// process location` part being crucial. Sorry misread the code. The ternary is only used for arguments to `location` consturctor, ie we can already see that the ternary is not necessary

Comment: would you clarify why the ternary is not necessary? I need the correct location constructor to be invoked, `const location&` constructor when `base_dir *parent` is a location, `const base_dir &` or `const server&` constructor when `base_dir *parent` is a server, while keeping the `server::server(const base_dir&)` method.

Comment: the conditional operator is useful in rare cases, eg conditionally initializing a reference. From the top of my head I don't know any case where it necessary. And it is definitely not useful in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of the error message is the last sentence:

```
main.cpp:54:48: note:   and each type can be converted to the other
```

I seems like you are not aware of what the conditional operator actually does. It is not a drop in replacment for an `if` - `else`. This will compile without issues (after adding `server(const base_dir &other)` back in):

```
if (auto p = dynamic_cast<location*>(parent)) {
    location loc(*p);
    // process location and add it to `parent`
    return parent;
} else {
    location loc(dynamic_cast<server&>(*parent));
    // process location and add it to `parent`
    return parent;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ahnn38hnx)

However, this is still too complicated. Rather than doing such casts and then conditionally calling one or the other constructor. The constructor could take a reference to base and do the checks internally.

The issue with the conditional operator is that the type of the conditional operator is the common type of the last two operands. So lets look closely:

```
location loc((dynamic_cast<location*>(parent) ? dynamic_cast<location&>(*parent) : dynamic_cast<server&>(*parent)));
```

Its `location&` and `server&`. A `server` can be converted to a `location` via `location::location(const server&)` and a `location` can be converted to a `server` via `server::server(const base_dir &other)`. Hence the resulting error message. Without the `server::server(const base_dir&)` converting cosntructor the resulting type of the conditional operator is `location&`, which actually makes the use of it here pointless. You cannot use the conditional operator for dynamic casts like this.

For more details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type.

---

Here is a simpler example to demonstrate how the conditional operator messes up your casting:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base {
    virtual ~base() {}
};
struct foo : base {};
struct bar : base {
    bar() = default;
    bar(const foo&) {}
};

void what_is_it(const base&) {std::cout << "base"; }
void what_is_it(const foo&) { std::cout << "foo"; }
void what_is_it(const bar&) { std::cout << "bar"; }

int main() {
    foo a;
    base& x = a;
    what_is_it( dynamic_cast<bar*>(&x) ? (std::cout << "true",dynamic_cast<bar&>(x)) : dynamic_cast<foo&>(x));
    std::cout << "\n";

    bar b;
    base& y = b;
    what_is_it( dynamic_cast<bar*>(&y) ? (std::cout << "true",dynamic_cast<bar&>(y)) : dynamic_cast<foo&>(y));
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/hfc8sqfMa):

```
bar 
truebar
```

Because for `x` the cast fails while for `y` the cast succeeds. Though in either case the conditional operator makes the result a `bar&` irrespective of the different type it is cast to before. The common type of `bar&` and `foo&` is `bar&`, because a `foo&` can be converted to a `bar&` (but not vice versa).

Comment: in `if (auto p = dynamic_cast<location*>(parent)) { location loc(dynamic_cast<location&>(*parent)); }`, the 2nd `dynamic_cast` is unnecessary since you already have the casted `location*` pointer from the 1st `dynamic_cast`, so just dereference that pointer, eg: `if (auto p = dynamic_cast<location*>(parent)) { location loc(*p); }`

Comment: In any case, I would probably change that `if` to something more like this: `location loc; /* or std::optional<location> loc; */ if (auto p = dynamic_cast<location*>(parent)) { loc = location(*p); } else { loc = location(dynamic_cast<server&>(*parent)); } /* process location and add it to parent */ return parent;`

Comment: On the other hand, it would be cleaner to let the `location(base_dir)` constructor do the casting and initialize the `location` as needed, then `process_location()` can become simply: `base_dir* process_location(base_dir *parent) { ... location loc(*parent); /* process location and add it to parent */ return parent; }`

Comment: thanks for explaining the ternary problem. thank you @Remy for providing the best alternative.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "On the other hand..." thats what I actually meant when I wrote "avoid the casts" and then i didnt pay attention and introduced more unnecessary casts :)

Comment: i still don't understand why `base_dir&` constructor is entered once `server(const base_dir&)` is uncommented. is it again because the sibling classes become convertible to each other? why doesn't that work? are they trying to implicitly convert into each other and `base_dir&` is the only compromise? will `explicit` keyword help?